# failed to properly import EPS file made with matplotlib to LaTeX

Tags: python, latex, matplotlib, postscript, eps

I made PDF and EPS files with matplotlib (the latest version from git repository, v1.1.0-538-g8b1e5b8, but the following problem happens also with the latest release) with following code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def func(x,y):
    return (1- x/2 + x**5 + y**3)*np.exp(-x**2-y**2)

xmin, xmax = -3, 3
ymin, ymax = -1.2, 1.2

x0 = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100, endpoint=True)
y0 = np.sin(x0)
x1 = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 10, endpoint=True)
y1 = np.sin(x1)

npix = 128
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, npix, endpoint=True)
y = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, npix, endpoint=True)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
img = func(X, Y)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 3))

ax_img = fig.add_subplot(131)
ax_img.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.binary_r, origin='lower', interpolation='nearest', resample=False)
ax_img.axis('off')

ax0 = fig.add_subplot(132)
ax0.plot(x0, y0, ls='-', c='0.4', lw=0.8, label='Test 1')
ax0.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
ax0.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
ax0.set_xlabel("This is X-label", fontsize='xx-large')
ax0.set_ylabel("This is Y-label", fontsize='xx-large')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(133)
ax2.plot(x0, y0, '-', c='0.4', lw=0.8, label='Test 2')
ax2.plot(x1, y1, 'o', c='0.4', lw=0.8, label='Test 2')
ax2.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
ax2.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
ax2.set_xlabel("This is X-label", fontsize='xx-large')
ax2.set_ylabel("This is Y-label", fontsize='xx-large')

fig_bottom = 0.05
fig_height = 0.9
fig_img_l  = 0.05
fig_img_w  = 0.15
fig_ax0_l = 0.25
fig_ax0_w = 0.4
fig_ax2_l = 0.7
fig_ax2_w = 0.25

ax_img.set_position([fig_img_l, fig_bottom, fig_img_w, fig_height])
ax0.set_position([fig_ax0_l, fig_bottom, fig_ax0_w, fig_height])
ax2.set_position([fig_ax2_l, fig_bottom, fig_ax2_w, fig_height])

art_txt1 = ax_img.text(0, 1.2, 'Header 1', ha='left', va='center', fontsize='x-large', transform=ax_img.transAxes)
art_txt2 = ax_img.text(0, 1.1, 'Header 2', ha='left', va='center', fontsize='x-large', transform=ax_img.transAxes)

fout_eps = 'mpl_test.eps'
fout_pdf = 'mpl_test.pdf'
plt.savefig(fout_eps, bbox_inches='tight', bbox_extra_artists=[art_txt1, art_txt2])
plt.savefig(fout_pdf, bbox_inches='tight', bbox_extra_artists=[art_txt1, art_txt2])
```

The EPS (http://db.tt/8anYHL2w) and PDF (http://db.tt/r6QSZQp7) files created with this script can be seen as expected with gv and Preview.app. (sorry for not linking as I'm limited to make 2 hyperlinks at this moment and one more below).

However, the image at the left panel of the EPS does not appear when I put the figure in LaTeX as follows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[bb= 0 0 1014.0875 257.796875, clip, width=0.95\linewidth]{mpl_test.pdf}
    \includegraphics[bb= 0 0 1014.0875 257.796875, draft, clip, width=0.95\linewidth]{mpl_test.pdf}
  \end{center}
  \caption{This is what I expect (PDF is used). Bottom panel shows BoundingBox of the figure on top panel by setting ``draft'' in \textbackslash{}includegraphics.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{mpl_test.eps}
    \includegraphics[draft,width=0.95\linewidth]{mpl_test.eps}
  \end{center}
  \caption{But in reality... (w/ EPS)}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Resulting PDF file: http://db.tt/J1GPthVO

The figure imported as PDF appears as expected, but EPS does not show the left panel put with "imshow" in matplotlib.  Also, the leftmost part of the Y-label is removed.

I'm not sure whether this is caused by matplotlib or LaTeX.  If someone knows how to solve the problem, I would be grateful.  I would like to create EPS directly with matplotlib rather than using conversion program such as pdf2eps.  And I need to use EPS for publication due to the publisher's regulation.

My environment is:

- Mac OS X 10.7.3
- Python 2.7.2 is installed with Homebrew
- LaTeX is installed by using MacTeX

Comment: Your example work fine with either `pdflatex` (`pdf` figures only) or `latex` (`eps` figures only) on my Ubuntu 10.04 with matplotlib 1.1.0 and TeXLive

Comment: I've pulled the latest development version of matplotlib and then edited ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc to set "ps.usedistiller: xpdf." This actually worked!  The setting was originally "False" and I tried to change this to xpdf several times with previous versions. So I guess both updating to the latest version and xpdf can handle the things properly (apparently behavior of "bbox_inches='tight' has got improved).  Thanks.